# How to serialize Timestamp into Json field in NiFi ValidateRecord processor / JsonRecordSetWriter

Tags: jackson, avro, apache-nifi

How to serialize Timestamp into Json field in NiFi `ValidateRecord` processor / `JsonRecordSetWriter`.

On input, I have a CSV file with a timestamp column with the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`.
In my NiFi Flow I have a `ValidateRecord` processor that is using `CSVReader` for reading and `JsonRecordSetWriter` as writer. Both of them are using Avro schema with the timestamp field defined as

```
"fields" : [ {
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : {
            "type" : "long",
            "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
        },
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '2016/10/08 07:51:00.000'"
    }, {
    ...
```

When a record with a field value like `2016-10-08 07:51:00.000` is coming through, I'm getting an exception in the NiFi logs:

```
2018-10-18 17:05:59,135 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-1] o.a.n.processors.standard.ValidateRecord ValidateRecord[id=3d44915d-a52a-3eb0-1ae1-7b0cbe4b1a03] Failed to write MapRecord[{timestamp=2016-10-08 07:51:00.0, ...  ] with schema {"type":"record","name":"redfunnel","doc":"Schema generated by Kite","fields":[{"name":"timestamp","type":{"type":"long","logicalType":"timestamp-millis"},"doc":"Type inferred from '2016/10/08 07:51:00.000'"},{ .... }]} as a JSON Object due to java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the generator, can only serialize simple wrapper types (type passed java.sql.Timestamp): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the generator, can only serialize simple wrapper types (type passed java.sql.Timestamp)
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ObjectCodec defined for the generator, can only serialize simple wrapper types (type passed java.sql.Timestamp)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase._writeSimpleObject(JsonGeneratorBase.java:556)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonGeneratorBase.writeObject(JsonGeneratorBase.java:317)
    at org.apache.nifi.json.WriteJsonResult.writeRawValue(WriteJsonResult.java:267)
    at org.apache.nifi.json.WriteJsonResult.writeRecord(WriteJsonResult.java:201)
    at org.apache.nifi.json.WriteJsonResult.writeRawRecord(WriteJsonResult.java:149)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateRecord.onTrigger(ValidateRecord.java:342)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

In the properties of my `JsonRecordSetWriter` I've tries to specify a format for writing a Timestamp as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

[image]

but unfortunately without success, I am still getting the same Exception in the NiFi logs.

Does that mean that `JsonRecordSetWriter` cannot serialize `java.time.Timestamp` by default even though it has `Timestamp Format` property for configuring seemingly exactly that?

Is it possible to write Timestamp according to a custom format using out-of-the-box NiFi components or I have to modify the `JsonRecordSetWriter`?

**Update**

Following up the code, my exception is getting thrown from [this code branch](https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-bundle/nifi-standard-processors/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/processors/standard/ValidateRecord.java#L342).
It seems that it is a branch for invalid records that did not pass validation. Maybe my error occurs only on invalid records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that I have found a configuration that works in my case.

I had to split the schema into two: one for the input and another one for the output.

So, the **schema1** defines the timestamp field as:

```
{
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '2016/10/08 07:51:00.000'"
}
```

and **schema2** defines the timestamp field as

```
{
    "name" : "timestamp",
    "type" : {
        "type" : "long",
        "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
    },
    "doc" : "Type inferred from '2016/10/08 07:51:00.000'"
}
```

Now I am configuring the `ValidateRecord` processor with

- CSVReader that uses **schema1**
- JsonRecordSetWriter that uses **schema2**
- The ValidateRecord's "Schema Text" field with **schema1**

After that the records pass my `ValidateRecord` processor without errors and land in the `timestamp` field of a Postgres database using `PutDatabaseRecord` processor that uses `JsonTreeReader` configured with **schema2**.

Important as well is to configure the `JsonTreeReader`'s Timestamp format property with the correct string format, e.g. 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS' in my case.

Hopefully that'll help in similar situation someone out there.

Comment: Hi, I am also stuck at this same juncture, I followed the same procedure but then in the validationRecord, if the data is string instead of timestamp then also it is counted as valid. A bit help would be appreciated on whether you considered this case or not.